# Struts2 using Struts1-Style Getter/Setter methods for indexed properties

Tags: java, struts2, struts, struts1

In Struts(1/2) a indexed property in the HTML-Page looks like this: `<input type="text" name="myIdxProp[1]" value="foo" />`

In Struts 1 the corresponding Getter/Setter-Methods which are called during bean population in the Struts-FormBean (Model) for this indexed properties looked like this:

```
public void setMyIdxProp(int index, String value){
   // Do something with the value
}
public String getMyIdxProp(int index) {
   String retVal = "" //get the value from somewhere
   return retVal;
}
```

Struts 2 is working working with Lists (or other Collections) in this way:

```
public List<String> getMyIdxProp(){
    return this.myIdxProp;
}
public void setMyIdxProp(List<String> myIdxProp){
    this.myIdxProp = myIdxProp;
}
```

**My question: Is there any way how I can teach Struts2 to use Struts1-style bean population for indexed properties?**

Maybe some kond of bean population interceptor or filter. The goal would be to be able to use both methods in the end (maybe with some flag to enable/disable the interceptor/filter).

Any hint is appreciated. I really don't know how to achieve this without changing all my StrutsForms.

Background: We have an old Struts1 application which should be revived and migrated to Struts2. The plan is to reuse Actions and Forms as much as possible.

Comment: just to clarify, you want to create a struts2 application out of a struts1 application copy-pasting templates and actions and delegating to an interceptor (a substitute of ParametersInterceptor I guess) the responsibility of doing the magic?

Comment: No. the goal is to migrate the Struts1 application to a Struts2 application (which works quite well so far using a similar concept to the struts2-struts1-plugin). So far Struts2 is running together with Struts1 as propsed in the Struts migration strategies. But we need to get rid of Struts1 in the end.

Comment: You're saying it doesn't work this way now?

Comment: The Struts1-style indexed property setters (first snippet in my post) are not working with struts2. We would need to add the struts2-style getters/setters (second snippet) to make the forms work with struts2. We have a lot of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwriting the Struts2 `ParamsInterceptor` did the trick for me.

Comment: Let me know, if you want to know more about an explicit implementation.